# Why when you enable the arrow on the ActionBar appears an icon with 3 lines?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

[image]

Hello, This is the code to enable the arrow (1)

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  // Desahibilita la fleac de arriba para el actionBarDrwaer
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Locales");
```

And this happend

[image]

Will you help me change it?

Comment: usually I don't get this behaviour. Did you follow an example? if so which?

Comment: @Delblanco I extend the class of Sherlock Activity, then assign title, icon and enabled the arrow

Comment: Did you find your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest for any custom style applied to the application:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"> <---Custom theme
    <activities....>
</application>
```

if a custom style is applied check that specific style for the following:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_your_new_home_up_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_your_new_home_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

This way the default `homeAsUpIndicator` is overridden to some custom drawable. If you remove you should get the default arrow back. Hope this helps!